# How to fix LayoutParam's for imageview ClassCaseException?

Tags: android, classcastexception

This is the error i get each time i try and set the LayoutParam's for a image view.

```
10-02 03:27:53.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 03:27:53.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1272): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams
10-02 03:27:53.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:659)
10-02 03:27:53.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:311)
10-02 03:27:53.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
10-02 03:27:53.081: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChild(ViewGroup.java:3109)
```

Here is my layout with the imageview i am trying to set the layoutParam's for..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView"
  android:layout_width="50dip"
  android:layout_height="50dip" android:src="@drawable/stub"  android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"   android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code i inflate the view and then try to set the Param's but i keep getting the error above.

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lazyitemt, null);


    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, image);
    return vi;
}
```

I dont know why i keep getting this. Everything seems to be right? How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put `imageView` inside LinearLayout. So, you should modify your layout param code like this

```
image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150));
```

Comment: This worked but the images now look Stretched and pixilated really bad.

Comment: why you set 150 px in layout param? that's strange. if you don't want image to be stretched, just delete code above and specify size of your image in  xml layout value of ImageView.

Comment: Well i want it to be different sizes depending on the Screen Size

Comment: Then I think you'd better change scaleType attribute. In `centerCrop` mode, image will be streched if ImageView is bigger than bitmap. If you don't want it, use 'center' scaleType.

Comment: you can see differences between scaleType here : http://mainia.tistory.com/473 . This post is written in Korean, but you can see difference by images.